# Limit maximum associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have two Models `Team` and `Match` and a `TeamMatch` association.

```rb
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teams, :through => :team_matches, :source => :team
    has_many :team_matches

    def attend(team)
        self.team_matches.create!(:team => team)
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        nil
    end
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :matches, :through => :team_matches, :source => :match
    has_many :team_matches
end

class TeamMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :match
    belongs_to :team
end
```

How do I restrict how many `Teams` can be assigned to a `Match`?

**EDIT:**
Update according to suggestions. `m = FactoryGirl.create(:team)`, `t..2 = FactoryGirl.create(:team)`

```
1.9.3p194 :005 > m.attend(t)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  TeamMatch Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `team_matches` WHERE (`team_matches`.`team_id` = BINARY 1 AND `team_matches`.`match_id` = 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `team_matches` (`match_id`, `team_id`) VALUES (1, 1)
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => #<TeamMatch id: 1, match_id: 1, team_id: 1> 
1.9.3p194 :006 > m.attend(t1)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  TeamMatch Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `team_matches` WHERE (`team_matches`.`team_id` = BINARY 2 AND `team_matches`.`match_id` = 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `team_matches` (`match_id`, `team_id`) VALUES (1, 2)
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => #<TeamMatch id: 2, match_id: 1, team_id: 2> 
1.9.3p194 :007 > m.attend(t2)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  TeamMatch Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `team_matches` WHERE (`team_matches`.`team_id` = BINARY 3 AND `team_matches`.`match_id` = 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `team_matches` (`match_id`, `team_id`) VALUES (1, 3)
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: In team model you can write a custom validation method like `validate :check_teams def check_teams if matches.size > 3 errors.add("cannot add more than 3 teams") end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use association callback.

```
has_many :teams, :through => :team_matches, :source => :team, :before_add => :limit_number_of_teams

def limit_number_of_teams(added_team)
  raise Exception.new('Team limit for the match reached') if teams.size >= 2
end
```

Comment: I have tested your suggestion, but my Test fails. It gives me this error `ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`
Updated my initial post to include the function for a `Team` to attend a `Match`

Comment: Check my update, as you can see, it doesn't care if I add a 3rd `Team`to the `Match`

Comment: Didi you set the limit to 2, or did you just copy my hardcoded 4? :)

Comment: Yes I have replaced your `>= 4` with `> 2`

Comment: Ok, few more things. First of alll your attend method doesn't make sense as it is creating a new team instead of assigning the existing one. All you need to assign team to association is `teams << team`. Unattend is not needed as well: `teams.delete team`. And most importantly, callback is run before adding the object hence there should be >= 2

Comment: No, it creates a new `TeamMatch` association not a new `Team`, as you can see, it passes the `team` to the method. I don't know if it matters that I delete the association or the `Team` associated to the `Match`.

Comment: Ah, true! In that case it will get around the callback. Could you change that method content to: `teams << team; rescue Exception; nil`

Comment: Ok, looks like it almost works now. My Test doesn't pass, but it can see the Exception, I have tried `@match.attend(@team3).should_not be_valid` but it differs from the Exception that gets thrown by the method

Answer (score 2):

I just realize there is much neater solution to that, which is possible as it is has_many through association:

```
class TeamMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :match
  belongs_to :team

  validate :teams_per_match_limit

  def teams_per_match_limit
    errors.add(:base, 'blah') if par.children.size > 1
  end

end
```

Comment: This works too if I create a new TeamMatch instead of a Team with the attend method, don't know which answer to mark as correct :)

Comment: This one is probably better, however has it downsides as well - (if you create a new match, you can assign any number of teams to it (before you save it do database) and valid? will return true. It will fail to save, and throw an axception, still, valid? should return false. Probably it might be fixed by adding ':validate => true` but it seems there might be more similar troubles.

Comment: which of your solutions would you suggest is better?

Comment: This one as there is no obvious way around (the second one wouldn't work for the attend method you posted in question).

Answer (score 0):

You should add some kind of custom validation like this:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teams, :through => :team_matches, :source => :team
    has_many :team_matches

  validate :max_associate

  def max_associate
    errors.add(:teams, "can not be added more than 5") if teams.length > 5
  end

end
```

Comment: Will this work? It will prevent from saving the Match if it has more than 5 matches, but won't prevent adding new match

Comment: It will always work, I think you didn't learn about custom validations.

Comment: yes it is ok........adding always check validation unless you do some `validate: false`...vote up

Comment: I have just check that, adding new object to association do not run parent validations. It saves the child and run child validations, but not parents.